# Explanation for the given solution

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

[image: This is the image of the problem statement and solution]

This is a question from a regional mathematics olympiad. Explain the proof how the various mentioned points are *concyclic* (i.e the theorem). Please explain the second paragraph of the solution.

Comment: The fact that a quadrilateral is cyclic iff opposite angles sum to $180^o$ is basic geometry. It is easy to prove: let cyclic quad be $ABCD$ and centre $O$. Extend $AO$ to $X$. Then $\angle XOB=\angle OBA+\angle OAB$. But triangle is isosceles, so that is $2\angle OAB$. Similarly for $XOC$. Hence (adding) $\angle BOC=2\angle BAC$. Similarly the other angle $BOC$ (ie $360^o$ minus first) is $2\angle BDC$. Hence result. For converse, take circumcircle of $ABC$ and let line $BD$ meet circle at $D'$. [Draw diagram]. Contradiction if $D\ne D'$.

Comment: How does $\angle KPQ = \angle PKL$, $\angle KPB = \angle PKB$ and $\angle LPQ = \angle LKQ$ prove that $K, L, P, Q$ are concylic?

Comment: All you need is $\angle LPQ=\angle LKQ$. That shows that $K,L,P,Q$ are concyclic. The starting point is to take two points $L,Q$ on a circle centre $O$. Then for points $P$ on the major arc $LQ$ we have $2\angle LPQ=\angle LOQ$. The converse is also easy to show. So if $K,P$ are both on the major arc we have $\angle LKQ=\angle LPQ$. Similarly if both are on the minor arc. If one is on one and one on the other then they sum to $180^o$. This is all basic stuff, just search on "cyclic quadrilateral".